# Django: Is there a way to use static with default_if_none?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

In my Django template I'm using `static` to  pull images from the `static/` folder based on each item's (byte) id property. An example of a path to an image would be: `static/images/promo-abc.png` I'm building the path to the image using `with`:

```
{% for byte in bytes %}
    {% with 'images/'|add:'promo-'|add:byte.id|add:'.png' as image_static %}
       <img class="promo-image" src="{% static image_static %}"/>
    {% endwith %}
```

However if there is no image based on the item's id I'd like the 'default' image to be used: `static/images/promo-dummy.png`. For that I'm trying to use `default_if_none` but so far this isn't working (getting error: `Could not parse some characters:`...)

```
{% with 'images/'|add:'promo-'|add:byte.id|add:'.png' as image_static %}
   <img class="promo-image" src="{{% static image_static |default_if_none:'images/promo-dummy.png' %}}"/>
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: Since byte appears to be a model instance why are you not using an ImageField (which would mean the file would be stored in media directory)? Static files are called static for a reason.

Comment: Avoid putting so much logic directly in templates. Consider creating a template tag to build the src path https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags